# Implementing 3 different Macros on Multiple Cells in a Sheet by Selection

Tags: vba

I am a complete noob at both excel and Vba and am trying to come up with code that can give me a timer and a cell color change that occurs when I click on my three buttons StartBtn, StopBtn and ResetBtn. Right now I got the code to work for a single cell B3 but need the buttons to work for any cell on the sheet that is clicked on. I am pasting the code below and hope you guys would be kind enough to go through the code and save this confused noob.

Code:

```
Dim StopTimer           As Boolean
Dim SchdTime            As Date
Dim Etime               As Date
Const OneSec            As Date = 1 / 86400#

 Private Sub StartBtn_Click()
   Range("B3").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
   StopTimer = False
   SchdTime = Now()
   [B3].Value = Format(Etime, "hh:mm:ss")
   Application.OnTime SchdTime + OneSec, "Sheet1.NextTick"
End Sub

Private Sub ResetBtn_Click()
    Range("B3").Interior.ColorIndex = -4142

    StopTimer = True
    Etime = 0
    [B3].Value = "00:00:00"
End Sub


Private Sub StopBtn_Click()
    Range("B3").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    StopTimer = True
    Beep
End Sub

Sub NextTick()
   If StopTimer Then
      'Don't reschedule update
   Else
      [B3].Value = Format(Etime, "hh:mm:ss")
      SchdTime = SchdTime + OneSec
      Application.OnTime SchdTime, "Sheet1.NextTick"
      Etime = Etime + OneSec
   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use `selection` instead of the range of B3?

Comment: Thanks Raystafarian! Tried out ur suggestion and it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

In excel you can use the [selection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840834.aspx) property to address what's selected or active in your worksheet.

Note, however, that this can cause problems further down the road as the code becomes more complex and using `selection` is *usually* not the best method.

Comment: Hey Ray..as you said the code works fine but when I click on another cell the active cell changes and hence the counter stops on the previous cell. I am hoping that the counter continues until I have clicked a stop button on that cell. Could you possibly help me out with that please?

Comment: That would be a completely different question

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use `Selection` throughout all your code,
I suggest that you use `Selection` to identify the currently selected cell
when you invoke your `StartBtn`, save that location,
and use it in the other routines; e.g.,

```
Dim StopTimer           As Boolean
Dim SchdTime            As Date
Dim Etime               As Date
Dim SavedLoc            As Variant                                 ' Here
Const OneSec            As Date = 1 / 86400#

Private Sub StartBtn_Click()
    If Selection.Count <> 1 Then
        MsgBox "Please select a single cell."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    SavedLoc = Selection.Address                                   ' Here
    Range(SavedLoc).Interior.ColorIndex = 6                        ' Here
    StopTimer = False
    SchdTime = Now()
    Range(SavedLoc).Value = Format(Etime, "hh:mm:ss")              ' Here
    Application.OnTime SchdTime + OneSec, "NextTick"
End Sub

Private Sub ResetBtn_Click()
    Range(SavedLoc).Interior.ColorIndex = -4142                    ' Here

    StopTimer = True
    Etime = 0
    Range(SavedLoc).Value = "00:00:00"                             ' Here
    SavedLoc = nul                                                 ' Here
End Sub

Private Sub StopBtn_Click()
    Range(SavedLoc).Interior.ColorIndex = 4                        ' Here
    StopTimer = True
    SavedLoc = nul                                                 ' Here
    Beep
End Sub

Sub NextTick()
    If StopTimer Then
        'Don't reschedule update
    Else
        Range(SavedLoc).Value = Format(Etime, "hh:mm:ss")          ' Here
        SchdTime = SchdTime + OneSec
        Application.OnTime SchdTime, "NextTick"
        Etime = Etime + OneSec
    End If
End Sub
```

If you want to run timers in multiple cells simultaneously,
then it becomes much more complicated,
and you should refer to the comments on [your other question](https://superuser.com/q/976698).

Comment: Thanks Scott.. I did need to run timers in multiple cells simultaneously but your suggestion helped me out immensely and finally cracked it...thank you so much...god bless!!