# VBA keep timer running until told to stop

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a VBA macro that starts a timer on every cell I click on using a start, stop and reset button. But the moment I click on another cell on the sheet (thus changing the active cell), my timer on the previous cell stops automatically.

I am wanting that it continues until I tell it to stop using the stop button.

I am posting the code below and hope you guys can have a  look at it and possibly help this newbie out :)

```
Dim StopTimer           As Boolean
Dim SchdTime            As Date
Dim Etime               As Date
Const OneSec            As Date = 1 / 86400#


 Private Sub StartBtn_Click()

   Etime = 0

   Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
   StopTimer = False
   SchdTime = Now()
   Selection.Value = Format(Etime, "hh:mm:ss")

   Application.OnTime SchdTime + OneSec, "Sheet1.NextTick"

End Sub


Private Sub ResetBtn_Click()
    Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = -4142
    StopTimer = True
    Etime = 0
    Selection.Value = "00:00:00"
End Sub


Private Sub StopBtn_Click()
    Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    StopTimer = True
    Beep
End Sub

Sub NextTick()

   If StopTimer Then
   'Dont Reschedule Update

   ElseIf Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
      Selection.Value = Format(Etime, "hh:mm:ss")
      SchdTime = SchdTime + OneSec
      Application.OnTime SchdTime, "Sheet1.NextTick"
      Etime = Etime + OneSec
   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You timer writer in NextTick function writes the timer value to "Selection.Value".  If you change cells, you change your 'Selection'.  I'd say you need to create individual timers for each cell (perhaps store them in an Array), and reference them individually as required.  As-is, your question is too broad (IMO), as there are MANY ways of accomplishing what you want, and your currently approach will require major reworking to accomplish your goal.

Comment: It came from [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/974915/implementing-3-different-macros-on-multiple-cells-in-a-sheet-by-selection) just for completeness' sake.

Comment: Is there no possible  way around this guys @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007@Raystafarian?

Comment: Yeah, use the start button for the timer and do everything else as `worksheetchange` until you hit the button again?

Comment: I agree with Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007's analysis of what is happening, but I have a different suggestion: if you don't want to have timers running in multiple cells simultaneously, then you should simply keep track of what cell (if any) holds the active timer.  Then `NextTick`, et.al., should refer to that saved location rather than the current `Selection`.

Comment: Hey guys...Thank you so much  for all your help...your suggestions  have been most helpful and I was finally able to crack it.. I created a list  that stores timer cell locations everytime I hit  the Start Button  on  a cell and deletes the  cell location  when I hit the Stop Button for  a  particular cell selection and also added an 'add time' function for every cell location in the list. Thank you all once again!